# Android Studio Theme editor not showing previews

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 1.5.1 my Theme Editor does not show previews for any theme I select.

[image]

I've tried making a new project and see whats happening there, but it's still not showin any preview.

I feel like I'm missing something silly.

Comment: Same issue. How do you solve?

Comment: @DaTi Are u using stable channel?

Comment: I filed a bug with android builds tools. Hopefully they will take a look at it. I know they're probably swamped with more important issues at the moment. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232087&q=theme%20editor%20preview&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Answer (score 6):

I noticed all the previews broke when I installed the Android N SDK. Switching the preview to API 23 fixes it for Layout previews, but not for the Theme Editor. Only way I got it to work for Theme Editor was by uninstalling the Android N SDK.

Comment: I will check that out tomorrow in the office, thanks!

Comment: I've deleted every Android N and/or Preview channel entry from my SDK manager, still no theme editor preview :(

Comment: With Android N still uninstalled, open up Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches and Restart. If that doesn't work Create a New Project with just the default settings and try again since I just noticed in your picture you're using a custom theme.

Comment: Progress!! In the new project I have the previews, but when I reopen the project that I'm working on, still nothing. Maybe something with my style.xml?

Comment: Updating the support libs and the android gradle plugin to the latest version, then invalidating the caches and restarting android studio worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me on Android Studio 2.3.1 Doing a 'Clean Project' from the Build menu fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. I have uninstalled Android studio and reinstalled the latest version. The problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. Try this:

1. go to File> Sync Project with Gradle Files
2. File > Invalidate caches/ Restart..

This worked for me.